# Type safe way to append field by name

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Trying to implement function, which receives object `O`, field name `N` and field value `T` returns object which has all fields from `O`, and field with name `N` which have type `T`

Tried to implement such way:

```
export function immutableAdd<O, N extends string, T>(object: O, name: N, value: T): O & { [key: N]: T } {
    return { ...object, [name]: value };
}

let a = { a: 3 };
let b = immutableAdd(a, 'test', 'value');
// `b` should have type { a: number, test: string } here
let c = b.test;
c === 'value'
```

But this code doesn't work, because there is error in this part: `{ [key: N]: T }` (An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number')

How to write return type for this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you have two options here: a) add a type assertion for `immutableAdd` return type or b) use a `Record` type. If you can change the function signature slightly, I would prefer b), as it is more concise/enforces stronger typing.

**a) [Type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEV0wW3yRgEMAjAG2AEEATWgHgHkAaOAOTlBmBVoGc4-GFEwoA5mwAqAPgAUAWABQcVXAhkAVsAwAuOKzgoS+YPvZsAbiQpIzcKQEp9TOADI4AbzgBtANbAAJ54uOwAuvpScAC+XspqcAD0iepQcGhQwCQ8QsBgJFDZwOk4wnAwEHAk-PzAsOUAFsUk9MC0cGBQEGB1MMF9PeooFIEA3HAUmAG68WrJJShlnd1wALxevsamEXDWtsWx1Rv+QSEcO1GxarOqmTBIULjeAHSvGtoYbD5bwDt7djEqoJXB5vCdgmJzpEYsposplFR4CQ1hsSPoAMwxUYI4DwMgoghEUiUGj0OQkNgAch4wkpVP+wEpjmxSkR6RRZGeNJgLLQa1W60pDMpQA)**

```
export function immutableAdd<O, N extends string, T>(
    object: O, name: N, value: T): O & { [key in N]: T } {
    // or create separate const to assert the added property type only; like:
    // const prop = { [name]: value } as { [key in N]: T }    
    return { ...object, [name]: value } as O & { [key in N]: T }
}

let b = immutableAdd({ a: 3 }, 'test', 'value'); // {a: number; } & { test: string; }
```

Note: I used a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) `{ [key in N]: T }` as part of the return type to include the `name` property. `{ [key: N]: T }` (what you used) indicates an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures), which can only have type `string` or `number`. In your case `N` is is a type parameter with constraint `extends string`, not `string`, hence the compiler error.

`return { ...object, [name]: value }` will resolve to the type `O & { [x: string]: T; }`, as the exact string literal type of `name` is unknown (we just know, that it extends `string`) and is therefore not be assignable to `O & { [key in N]: T }`, so we cast.

**b) [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=90&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEV0wW3yRgEMAjAG2AEEATWgHgHkAaOAOTlBmBVoGc4-GFEwoA5mwAqAPgAUAWABQcVXAhkAVsAwAuOKzhgoEMMFgBPfQCUd0RuxayAlPqZwAZHADecANoA1sAWeLjsALr6UnAAvj7KanBQwDBIULi%20AHTZGtoYbNmZxqbmMCExANzKMcrKVPBkcAC8eITE5FR0tHI%20cCT6AMyxbL48wvoA5ABuJBRIwBOxzhVwAPSrvf1wKEj4ZOYrcV6jwONCImLih3UpcGjNcGSZYzBVSvdNn3DTs-MTQA) type**

```
export function immutableAdd<O, N extends string, T>(
    object: O, property: Record<N,T>): O & { [key in N]: T } {
    return { ...object, ...property };
}

let b = immutableAdd( { a: 3 }, { test: 'value' }); // { a: number; } & { test: string; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggested return type is this:

```
O & {[key : string] : T}
```

or this:

```
O & {[key : number] : T}
```

It seems that the type of fields names can only be string or number

Comment: `{ [key in N]: T }` is OK.